# Is Node a variable in "Node next;" in Node class linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list

```
class Node {

    int data;

    Node next;


    Node(int d) { data = d; }

}
```

Why in a Node class we use Node as a variable by writing "Node next;", is it a variable or something else.

I know it acts as pointer kind of stuff but could you elaborate why a class name act as variable or whatever to refers to the next Node ?

Comment: We use `Node` as a type, not as a variable. as to *why*, in a linked list what is the next link of the list? And what type is its "next" node?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Node class defines a Java object, then any variable with type Node is actually a reference (a pointer) to a Node class object, including the next member of the Node class.